# Map all subdomains to another domain with nginx

Tags: nginx

With this sever config I can redirect all requests to another domain:

```
server {
    server_name example.net;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;

    return 301 https://other.net$request_uri;
}
```

but how can I redirect all subdomains to a new domain?

```
www.example.net     -->   www.other.net
webmail.example.net -->   webmail.other.net
forum.example.net   -->   forum.other.net
```

Can I use a placeholder in the return command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression in `server_name`:

```
server {
  server_name ~^(?P<subdomain>.+\.)example\.net$ ;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  return 301 https://${subdomain}other.net$request_uri;
}
```

---

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101952/nginx-forward-www-and-non-www-requests-to-one-directory/7118739#7118739) as there are few variants on specifying regular expressions in Nginx.